# Creating an automatic windows task that runs cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

Hey guys I have no idea how to make windows scripts or what language or anything so I need your help.  I am trying to create a scheduled task that will run once a week, open cmd.exe, enter 2 lines of code, then close cmd.exe

if it helps the code i need to run is:

dir d: /b >> c:\some_text_file.txt

dir f: /b >> c:\some_text_file.txt

Comment: Write a batch file that executes those two lines of code. Create a scheduled task that runs `cmd /c <fullpathandnameof\yourfile.bat>`. Make sure that the location you're writing `some_text_file.txt` is writable by the account used to run the scheduled task (`C:\` will not be). Now you have the two tasks that need to be accomplished. Start by researching the first (executing commands in a batch file), which you should be able to find with a simple search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ken, I was able to schedule a task to run a batch file.

this link helped me figure out how to start http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm

Answer (score 0):

You only need a one line command

```
dir d: f: /b >> c:\some_text_file.txt
```

To Schedule

```
 SCHTASKS /Create /S ComputerName /U user /P password /RU runasuser /RP runaspassword /SC WEEKLY /TN "Weekly Filelist" /TR "cmd /c dir d: f: /b >> c:\some_text_file.txt"
```

To schedule as you on your machine

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC WEEKLY /TN "Weekly Filelist" /TR "cmd /c dir d: f: /b >> c:\some_text_file.txt"
```